# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: Y400sX902 : While using Spark Kmeans

Tags: scala, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to use spark MLlib - kmeans to cluster a product dataset. But my first column i.e. ID starts with Y400sX902 and it throws an error as NumberFormatException when I run the below code. I am new to this technology and if there are any pointers to help then it would be great. Thanks.

```
object KMeansExmp {

def main(args: Array[String]) {

val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[1]").setAppName("KmeansApp");  
val sc = new SparkContext(conf);

val rawData = sc.textFile("/Users/Downloads/data.csv")
val header = rawData.first

val rows = rawData.filter(l => l != header)

val extractedFeatureVector = rows.map { row => Vectors.dense(row.split(',').map(_.toDouble).slice(2, 5)) }


val numberOfClusters = 3
val numberOfInterations = 50

val model = KMeans.train(extractedFeatureVector, numberOfClusters, numberOfInterations)

model.clusterCenters.foreach(println)

}
```

Error :

```
   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""Y400sX902""
   at         sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1250)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at    scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toDouble(StringLike.scala:232)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toDouble(StringOps.scala:31)
    at KMeansExmp$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(KMeansExmp.scala:22)
    at KMeansExmp$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(KMeansExmp.scala:22)
    at ........
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
val rows = rawData.drop(1)
```

instead of filtering the entire `RDD` to remove the first row (namely the non-numeric header).